# make php code shorter with conditional statements?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, shorthand

A few years ago I did a course of PHP but most of the knowledge has faded. So I've got a question. 
In a Joomla form (RSForms by RSJoomla) I am using repetitive code like this:

```
$locatie01 = $_POST['form']['locatie_01'];
$locatie02 = $_POST['form']['locatie_02'];
$locatie03 = $_POST['form']['locatie_03'];
$locatie04 = $_POST['form']['locatie_04'];
$locatie05 = $_POST['form']['locatie_05'];
$locatie06 = $_POST['form']['locatie_06'];
```

and this goes on till it reaches 100. (the location (spelled 'locatie' in Dutch) is posted to the database.
A bit further down, we're doing something similar but then with more elaborate code, so I'll just list 3:

```
 $db->setQuery("
     INSERT INTO #__instellingen
     (type,instelling,locatie,contactpersoon,telefoon,email,ivvu,vgu,token)
     VALUES
     ('".$type."','".$instelling."','".$locatie01."','".$contactpersoon."','".$telefoon."','".$email."','".$ivvu."','".$vgu."','".$token."')
 ");
 $db->query();

 if(!empty($locatie02)){
 $db->setQuery("
     INSERT INTO #__instellingen
     (type,instelling,locatie,contactpersoon,telefoon,email,ivvu,vgu,token)
     VALUES
     ('".$type."','".$instelling."','".$locatie02."','".$contactpersoon."','".$telefoon."','".$email."','".$ivvu."','".$vgu."','".$token."')
 ");
 $db->query();
 }

 if(!empty($locatie03)){
 $db->setQuery("
     INSERT INTO #__instellingen
     (type,instelling,locatie,contactpersoon,telefoon,email,ivvu,vgu,token)
     VALUES
     ('".$type."','".$instelling."','".$locatie03."','".$contactpersoon."','".$telefoon."','".$email."','".$ivvu."','".$vgu."','".$token."')
 ");
 $db->query();
 }
```

And this also continues to 100

What we are doing here, is: the first line is always filled (required field) and from then on: if 2 is not empty, send the data to the database, same for 3 etc.

Now I can tell this is not the shortest way of coding, and I vaguely remember we were able to write shorter code; was it with coditional coding? if .... a++. I'm sorry, I can't remember.... Can anyone refresh my memory?

Thanx,

Thom

Comment: Loops and functions...

Comment: sounds familiar, Lars. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself naming things `$foo_1, $foo_2, etc` it means you should probably be using an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, I don't know where the `$token` var comes from so I am going to suppose it comes from the form.
Also, I guess for the DB you are using the `PDO` object but it is almost the same for `mysqli` driver.

You can do something like that:

```php
foreach($_POST['form'] as $key) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO #__instellingen (type, instelling, locatie, 
    contactpersoon, telefoon, email, ivvu, vgu, token) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$key['type'], $key['instelling'], $key['locatie'], $key['contactpersoon'], $key['telefoon'], 
    $key['email'], $key['ivvu'], $key['vgu'], $key['token']);
}
```

The '?' mean bound parameter.
It is important you use a prepared statement in order to add a layer for avoiding SQL injections in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the query is the same for every element, you could do something like this. Also no need to check if it exists since you will only be handling the values in the array. You need to use prepared statements and sanitize here, do not insert raw form data into the database.

```
foreach($_POST['form'] as $key => $locatie) {
  $db->setQuery("
     INSERT INTO #__instellingen
     (type,instelling,locatie,contactpersoon,telefoon,email,ivvu,vgu,token)
     VALUES ('".$type."','".$instelling."','".$locatie."','".$contactpersoon."','".$telefoon."','".$email."','".$ivvu."','".$vgu."','".$token."')
 ");
}
```

Comment: This would assume that there is not other data in the form.

Comment: @NigelRen It is true that the correct answer depends on what is in post but that wasn't provided.

Comment: Yes & No, IMHO an answer should be able to anticipate problems but also you cannot (AFAIK) be psychic and be able to understand other issues OP may be having.  It's like (as you mentioned) that answering a question about SQL without talking about using prepared statements.